# I can't figure out how to navigate to a previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navigationcontroller

I have two ways of navigating to a form that I'm using. However, once this form has been submitted, I would like to return to the previous page that I was on. Is there a certain url path that I can navigate to based on which page I was on previously?

I'm using just a standard form and a mvc architecture.

Here's my controller for this form:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateConversationViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            _ConversationManager.Create(model.Message, model.GetReceivers(), model.SenderId);
            return RedirectToAction("Me", "People");
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            ex.AddToModelState(ViewData.ModelState);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

when I return to the People/Me page, that would only redirect to one of the pages.

Comment: for this use session variable to store the previous location and then redirect to that page from this method

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of this? I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) Property. Be aware that in can be spoofed quite easily. The best way to do this is to store the previous page on the current user's session, or you can hide the previous URL in the ViewModel as explanied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772947/asp-net-mvc-return-to-previous-page).

I hope this helps, good luck!